# How to prevent GeolocateControl from zooming out

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm adding a GeolocateControl in my Mapbox maps. It works fine and displays my current position. However it zoom way too much out out. By default my map is zoom at 10. But when I click the GeolocateControl is travels to new destination and zooms out. I've tried adding zoom: 10, but no luck...

```
map.addControl(

    new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    zoom: 10,

    positionOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true,
   })
 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted to follow the documentation, but basically instead of `zoom` going directly on the object you provide, it needs to go on an object called `fitBoundsOptions`:

```
map.addControl(
    new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
        fitBoundsOptions: {
            zoom: 10,
        },
        positionOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        trackUserLocation: true,
   })
 );
```

Comment: To add to this answer, it's worth noting that, per the GeolocateControl documentation in the GL JS API reference, "The zoom level applied will depend on the accuracy of the geolocation provided by the device." This explains why clicking on the control causes the map to "zoom out" a lot. Specifying a zoom in a fitBoundsOptions allows you to work around this behavior.

Comment: To add to Adriana's comment, there's good reason why the default is like this, because if the device is only reporting a city wide accuracy, it's misleading to zoom in any further than city level.